# Run time Error 1004: Method 'Select' of Object 'Sheets' failed occurs every other time

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I get the error **Run time Error 1004: Method 'Select' of Object 'Sheets' failed** at the following line of code of VBA within Excel:

```
Application.Run "'Template.xls'!newSheet"
```

I am not the owner of Template.xls, and the 'newSheet' macro is password protected, so I know it is supposed to copy a worksheet, but I don't know exactly how it is doing it.

Some things to note:

1. My macro opens Template.xls before attempting to run Application.Run     "'Template.xls'!newSheet"
2. The run time error 1004 occurs **exactly every other time** I run my macro. So my macro works every other time.
3. The run time error **never** occurs when the Template.xls file is already open.
4. When I use a 'Stop' statement after opening Template.xls in my macro, the error **never** occurs.

What I've tried without success:

1. Since the error never occurs when there's a 'Stop' statement, I tried pausing with Application.Wait.
2. Since the error only occurs every other run, I've tried to use error handling to make the code rerun. Error handling is ignored with the external macro.

```
On Error Goto retry:
Application.Run "'Template.xls'!newSheet"
```

3. Since the macro never occurs when Template.xls is already open, I tried opening Template.xls in one macro, then setting a schedule for my macro which includes Application.Run "'Current Fed Template.xls'!newSheet"

```
Sub rnsb()
  Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Documents\Template.xls")
  Application.OnTime Now + 0.000095, "'MyMacro'"
End Sub
```

4. Since the error only occurs every other time, I thought there might be a global variable/switch in Template.xls that causes the 'newSheet' macro to behave differently every other time. Because the macro is password protected, it is impossible to know.

Comment: It’s quite easy to find how to unlock a vbproject if you Google for that.  Will be faster than us trying to guess what’s wrong with the method you’re calling

Comment: As a wild stab in the dark, something in the code could be telling the sheet to change visibility and then try and select it.  That would cause the error every other time.  `Public Sub test(): Sheet2.Visible = Not Sheet2.Visible: Sheet2.Select: End Sub`.  Pure guesswork though.

Comment: I had no idea you can unlock a vbproject. That ended up helping me confirm that the issue was with the Template.xls file running a Workbook_Open macro which executed based on a Boolean global variable. The macro would attempt to change visibility depending on the bool. I still don't understand why the bool alternated each time I ran my code. I'm assuming the global variable of the Template.xls file continues to exist in the Excel instance after the Template.xls file is closed.